# Building a tree from Stream using Scala

Tags: scala, tree

I want to build a tree which is read from a file of random height in this exact format,

```
       1
      2 3
     4 5 6
    . . . .
   . . . . .
```

using the following structure

```
case class Tree[+T](value : T, left :Option[Tree[T]], right : Option[Tree[T]])
```

The challenge I am facing is I have to read until the last line before I can build the tree because `left` and `right` is read only. The way I tried was,

1. Read the first line, create an node with a value (1) with `left` and `right` set to `None`.
2. Read the second line, create nodes with values (2) and (3), `left` and `right` set to `None`. This time, a new node (1) is created with `left` = node(2) and `right` = node(3).
3. Read the third line,  create nodes with values (4), (5) and (6), with `left` and `right` set to `None`. Create new node(2) and node(3) with node(2) -> node(4) and node(5) and node(3) -> node(5) and node(6) and finally, node(1) -> new node(2) and node(3)
4. Repeat until end of line.

At the end of it, I should have this relationship,

```
         1
        /  \
       2    3
      / \   / \
     4   5 5  6
    / \ /\ /\ / \
   .  .. . .. .  .
```

Any good advice for me? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1**

This solution works recursively and needs all lines to be already read. You are always at one row. If there are more rows, you create the `Tree`s for these first. Basically it will first create `Tree`s for the leaves.

When you have them, you know that the first and the second `Tree` form the new `Tree`. The second and the third form the second new `Tree` and so on. This is what `sliding` does.

As an example for sliding: `List(1,2,3,4).sliding(2) = List(List(1,2),List(2,3),List(3,4))`

In this solution I did not pay attention to efficiency though. The result is an `Option[Tree]`. `None` is yielded in case where there is no value/no line at all. It does not deal with cases where the string might be malformed.

```
case class Tree[+T](value : T, left :Option[Tree[T]], right : Option[Tree[T]])

def buildTree[T](lines: IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[T]]) = {
  def recurse[T](lines: IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[T]]): IndexedSeq[Tree[T]] = lines match {
    case line +: IndexedSeq() => line.map(Tree(_, None, None))
    case line +: rest => {
      val prevTrees = recurse(rest)
      (line, prevTrees.sliding(2).toIndexedSeq).zipped
      .map{case (v, IndexedSeq(left, right)) => Tree(v, Some(left), Some(right))}
    }
    case _ => IndexedSeq.empty
  }
  recurse(lines).headOption
}
```

Example:

```
val input = """1
2 3
4 5 6""".stripMargin

val lines = input.lines.map(_.filterNot(_ == ' ').toIndexedSeq).toIndexedSeq
//Vector(Vector(1), Vector(2, 3), Vector(4, 5, 6))

val result = buildTree(lines)
```

which results in:

`Some(Tree(1,Some(Tree(2,Some(Tree(4,None,None)),Some(Tree(5,None,None)))),Some(Tree(3,Some(Tree(5,None,None)),Some(Tree(6,None,None))))))`

Random insider (ignore please): I kinda like `zipped` now

**Solution 2**

This is a solution like you described it. It goes down from top to bottom and updates the tree after each insertion. It has to keep track of the head though, because when we want to insert leaves we have to modify all parent nodes, which reference is not stored in `Tree`.
I have to admit that things got pretty messy with all these `Option`s.

```
def buildTree2[T](lines: Iterator[IndexedSeq[T]]) = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(current: IndexedSeq[Tree[T]], head: Option[Tree[T]] = None): Option[Tree[T]] = {
    if(lines.hasNext) {
      val newTrees = lines.next.map(v => Option(Tree(v, None, None)))
      if(!current.isEmpty) {
        val h = (current, newTrees.sliding(2).toIndexedSeq).zipped.foldLeft(head.get) {
          case (nextHead, (parent, IndexedSeq(left, right))) => updateTree(nextHead, parent, Tree(parent.value, left, right))
        }
        loop(newTrees.flatten, Some(h))
      } else loop(newTrees.flatten, newTrees.head)
    } else head
  }

  def updateTree[T](head: Tree[T], target: Tree[T], replacement: Tree[T]): Tree[T] = {
    if(head eq target) {
      replacement
    } else head match {
      case Tree(v, Some(l), Some(r)) => Tree(v, Option(updateTree(l, target, replacement)), Option(updateTree(r, target, replacement)))
      case _ => head
    }
  }
  loop(IndexedSeq.empty)
}
```

Now we can use it with an iterator.

```
val lines = input.lines.map(_.filterNot(_ == ' ').toIndexedSeq)
buildTree2(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems simplest just to read the lines in the opposite order (provided that you can fit the entire file into memory). Otherwise, your approach would work fine.

Comment: Thanks. Solution 2 answered my question. However, there is a small surprise there when Tree grew big because updateTree(...) was not tail recursed and loop was depending on it.

Comment: Yes, that can be a problem. I'm not quite sure how to improve it though.